# How to keep a column in a new array, based on numbers that exist in other column?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have this matrix:

```
aux333=[2   0  ;
        2   0  ;
        2   0  ;
        2   0  ;
        2   0  ;
        2   0  ;
        2   0  ;
        2   0  ;
        2   0  ;
        2   0  ;
        2   0  ;
        2   0  ;
        2   0  ;
        2   0  ;
        2   0  ;
        2   70 ;
        3   0  ;
        2   0  ;
        2   0  ; 
        2   0  ;
        2   0  ;
        2   0  ;
        2   0  ;
        2   208;
        2   0  ;
        2   0  ;
        2   0  ;
        2   0  ;
        2   0  ;
        0   37 ;
        0   0  ;
        0   0  ;
        0   0  ; 
        0   0  ]
```

and I want to write some code that, if the first column is different from zero, a new array (`aux3final`) will receive the second column of `aux333`.

I tried writing it like this:

```
for j=1:length(aux333)
  if aux333(j,1)==2 | aux333(j,1)==3
     aux3final(j)=aux333(j,2);%%aux3final tá com dimensão 296, devia estar com dimensão 69
  end
```

but this isn't working at all. How to proceed?

The original code is bigger than what I posted, may be there is some variable influencing something.

Comment: Do you want to copy the entire second column if any  element in the first column is  non-zero? Or do you want to copy only those rows of the second column for which the element in the first column is non-zero?

Comment: From your code, it seems that you want the later one. You should be getting the required output. (is it that you forgot to use `end` in your original code?) A simpler way of that is `aux3final=aux333(logical(aux333(:,1)),2);`, What is your exact expected output?

Comment: To make your question cleaner I recommend deleting some rows in your example table so readers don't have to scroll.  Keep it [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: dude ur a wizzard of matlab! thx u so much! i didnt knew about this logical function, ill try to understand that

Comment: can u ask me what did u wrong with my for/if code? how could it work with for/if? im asking because i will have to it again soon or later

Comment: if im not asking too much, can u also explain me this logical function? i didnt  get it

Answer (score 1):

As Sardar pointed out, it is not clear whether the resulting vector (aux3final) should have

1) the same length as the input vector(aux333)

```
%find entries of interest
flg_valid=aux333(:,1)>0;
%alloc output
aux3final=zeros(size(aux333,1),1);
%copy index depending
aux3final(flg_valid)=aux333(flg_valid,2);
```

or

2) it has the length of the entries of interest

```
%extract only entries of interest
aux3final=aux333(flg_valid,2);
```